# Rich Intellisense for Lua

Tags: lua, intellisense, monaco-editor

I am using  the Monaco Editor for my C# program, and I want to know how to add rich intellisense for Lua.
For example, if I type something, it requests to put it.

Comment: Can someone please help me? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, I must say that this clearly isn't easy and requires a pretty huge effort. Basically, you will have to analyse the code yourself, and then make suggestions based upon the information you have gathered by analysing.

I can't go into detail about how you can or should analyse the code, because this is a huge task. When you analyse the code, you will have to understand what is what and you (probably) cannot do this by some simple regex. A very complicated example is the [TypeScript integration](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-typescript) but there are more simple examples, for example the [HTML plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-html). I can only recommend to take a look there for inspiration.

When you've analysed the code, you're basically good to go. You can then guess what the user wants to do next, or, for example, suggest methods or fields of the object they're currently accessing.

You can then suggest completions, which is done by handing Monaco a JSON object over (actually a TypeScript class, but more on that later). There is an [example at the Monaco Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-completion-provider-example) which shows how that can be done. A minimalistic provider could look like this:

```js
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider ("lua", {    // Or any other language...
  provideCompletionItems: (model, position) => {
    // Retrieve the text until the current cursor's position, anything
    // after that doesn't really matter.
    var textToMatch = model.getValueInRange ({
      startLineNumber: 1,
      startColumn: 1,
      endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
      endColumn: position.column
    });

    // Return JSON array containing all completion suggestions.
    return {
      suggestions: [
        // Example: io.write ()
        {
          label: "io.write (string)",
          kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
          documentation: "Writes a string to stdout.",
          insertText: "io.write (\"\")"  // Escape JSON as needed.
        },  // Other items.
      ]
    };
  }
});
```

Check out Monaco's documentation on [`CompletionItemKind`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/enums/monaco.languages.completionitemkind.html) for the different types of completion items and on [`CompletionItemProvider`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.completionitemprovider.html) for the "class" which we hand over as a JSON object to [`registerCompletionItemProvider ()`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html#registercompletionitemprovider). The Monaco documentation has all these different types and classes because Monaco is originally written in [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), but these classes and types can be resembled by a plain old JSON object as well.

You can basically "construct" a "rich" IntelliSense provider by calling all the different `register...Provider ()` functions [documented here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html).

If you want to have really helpful IntelliSense, then I would recommend not to forget about the `registerSignatureHelpProvider ()` method, which displays the "peek definition" windows on mouse-over over a type for which a definition is available.

Anyway, this is a really tedious task. And if you look at the file which is responsible for TypeScript IntelliSense (`src/lib/typescriptServices.js` in the TypeScript integration repo), it is 6.51 MB in size. Although it also contains a formatter, etc., it gives you a good impression of the work required and why I can't go into detail about implementing IntelliSense right here.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider connecting a Lua [language server](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) into Monaco via the help of TypeFox's [monaco-languageclient](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient) library. That still won't be easy though.

Answer (score 0):

In current version 0.17.1 an additional `range` property is needed in returned object:

```
return {
   suggestions: [
   // Example: io.write ()
   {
       label: "io.write (string)",
       kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
       documentation: "Writes a string to stdout.",
       insertText: "io.write (\"\")",  // Escape JSON as needed.
       range: {
          startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
          endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
          startColumn: position.column,
          endColumn: position.column
       }
   },  // Other items.
   ]
};
```